# Regular Expression with quotations

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var a = 'New York or "United States or Canada" OR "England or France" Or Mexico';
```

I want an array that is like the following:

```
 var b = ['New York','United States or Canada', 'England or France', 'Mexico'];
```

Basically, should split all the ORs except for the ones between quotes.

I need to do this in Javascript, I can't seem to get the regex to work perfectly. Is it possible to do it using just Regex or would I have to use Regex + some javascript logic to make it work.

Comment: Can't do this with only RegEx, you'd need lookbehinds, which aren't supported yet. :(

Comment: @ElliotBonneville apparently you're wrong ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
var b = a.split(/\s+or\s+(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/i)
```

Comment: Yup it works. However, the ones with the quotes have the quotes (i.e: the second entry shows as '"United States or Canada"' rather than 'United States or Canada')

Answer (score 1):

It is easiest use the php explode function to split the array on the "OR"s if you can use PHP. However, if you must use only Javascript, try something like the above answerer recommended.

Answer (score 0):

well the simplest way, would be to "force" putting quotes around each group:

```
var a = '"New York" or "United States or Canada" OR "England or France" Or "Mexico"';
var out = a.replace("OR", "or").replace("Or", "or").split('" or "')
[ '"New York',
  'United States or Canada',
  'England or France',
  'Mexico"' ]
```

but you may consider it's somehow cheating.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this using only RegExes is not advisable, though it most certainly is possible in some implementations, possibly even JavaScript. The language you describe is not regular and RegExes are thus not the best solution to this problem (even though non regular languages can be parsed with additions such as lookaheads/-behinds, balancing groups, recursion, etc.). RegExes might however help in the implementation of such a parser. The following code should do what you want.

```
function splitOnOr(str) {
    var patterns, pos, res, tokens, inQuotes;
    patterns = [
        { name: "or", expr: /^\s+or\s+/i },
        { name: "words", expr: /^\w+/ },
        { name: "whitespace", expr: /^\s+/ },
        { name: "quote", expr: /^"/ }
    ];
    pos = 0;
    res = [""];
    tokens = [];
    inQuotes = false;
    while (pos < str.length) {
        for (i = 0; i < patterns.length; ++i) {
            m = patterns[i].expr.exec(str.substr(pos));
            if (m) {
                pos += m[0].length;
                tokens.push({type: patterns[i].name, payload: m[0]});
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < tokens.length; ++i) {
        switch (tokens[i].name) {
            case "quote":
                inQuotes = !inQuotes;
                break;
            case "or":
                if (!inQuotes) {
                    res.push("");
                    break;
                }
            case default:
                res[res.length-1] += tokens[i].payload;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Is this overkill? Yes, but I was trying to make a point and demonstrate some best practices here: RegExes are not always the best solution and this kind of code will scale to way more complex rules and problems. And it is probably faster, too. I am following the basic principles of compiler design here (stress on *basic*). This takes the input stream and sperates it into a list of tokens: ors, other words, whitespace and quotes. It then consumes these tokens one by one and dispatches to the appropriate code for each kind of token that then generates the appropriate output.